# AKS create a Load Balancer itself. Purpose and usage of the sma ein not clear

Tags: azure-aks

I am working on AKS... AKS create a Load Balancer... Purpose and usage is not clear.

Searched google to understand the same. But no such detail is there.

Comment: In AKS, the nodes do not expose to the Internet, so if you need to access the application from the Internet, you must create the load balancer for your service. See the [description in AKS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-network#services).

Comment: Suppose you have more than one pods ( or services) are deployed on AKS. Not all AKS nodes contains all the pods (or service). Then how a normal Azure Load Balancer come to know that which service is installed on which node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comment. In AKS, the nodes do not expose to the Internet, so if you need to access the application from the Internet, you must create the load balancer for your service.

Actually, the load balancer is associated with the service which listens to the deployment and the service is a unique one. The deployment will help you manage the pods, so the load balancer just needs to know the service.

You can take a look at the [Kubernetes Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/). And see its description in AKS [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-network#services).

**Update**

When you create the service with a load balancer, and the AKS will create the load balancer rule for that service. The rule will name dependent on the uid of the service. See the screenshot of them:

[image]

[image]

You can use the command `kubectl edit service serviceName` to see the service uid.

Comment: @TarunKukreja You just question how to understand the load balancer in AKS. That is what I answer to.

Comment: Sorry, but I feel that I am not able to explain my concern here. Let's me retry to explain my concern or query..... (I will explain my doubts in N comments due to chars limit)

Comment: For e.g. I have AKS system configured. The system have 6 VMs - VM1, VM2, VM3 etc. I have few Container Images running on those VMs as PODs. Three services are configured as Cluster IP with Cluster IP like 10.0.14.10 and external IP as none. One nginx-ingress-controller is set as LoadBalancer with external IP set. nginx-ingress-controller is running on 3 VMs out of 6 VMs.

Comment: Now call proceed like Internet  >> Azure Load Balancer >> nginx-ingress-controller > the 3 services in which external ip is set as null.           Now I am able to see the setting from where call goes from Internet to Load Balancer, setting how call going from nginx-ingress-controller to my 3 services.

Comment: But concern coming how call goes from Azure Load Balance to ingress controller.. Note: Azure Load Balancer have configured all 6 VMs as backend pool and all VMs are healthy but nginx-ingress-controller is running on only 3 VMs. Then how it works? I have read the link shared, it says that it works.... but how doesn't give complete picture.

Comment: @TarunKukreja It all dependents on the load balancer rules and the health probe. The rules are created by the AKS with a special name that dependents on the service in the AKS.

Comment: Yes, I understand the same. But I was not able to create clear picture of communication between Azure Load Balancer and nginx-ingress controller by looking the rule and healt probe.

AKS create a Load Balancer with name as kubernetes. It settings are :- Backend pools (All 6 VMs).. 
Load Balancing rules - Two rules - One for 443 port and other for 80 port. Both rules are based on 2 health probes.
Health Probe - 2 Health Probe - Checking at 2 random ports on 2 VMs with TCP protocol.

Comment: @TarunKukreja you can check with the rules name. It will most the same as the uuid with the services in the AKS.

Comment: I have tried with POD UUID but no luck.... Would you please guide me the command or way to know uuid of a Service?

Comment: Thanks Charles Xu... Your current screen shot is making sense... I will check the same in my environment and will confirm the same within 1 or 2 days.

Comment: Yeah, it is same as Service UID... Now one small doubt :- How is rule name coming into picture for Azure Load Balancer?

Comment: @TarunKukreja Azure creates for you when you create the service with the load balancer type.

Comment: OK.. It means, Azure Load Balancer redirect request to the service having UID same as rule name....But how is redirection based on rule name working? It is like black box for me now... If you know let me know the same else I am okay to accept your reply as answer.

Comment: @TarunKukreja That's the function of the Azure Load Balancer. Actually, the AKS nodes are also Azure VMs. And I cannot explain it with little works. So you should learn about the [Azure Load Balancer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-overview) how does it work.

Comment: Ok... Thanks .... I am accepting your reply as answer with one doubt as opened :(